# Have multiple <select> elements share the same options in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select

So I have a React component like:

```js
export default function ExampleComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <select required name="select1">
                <option label=" "></option>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>

            <select name="select2">
                <option label=" "></option>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Continuing on for multiple more selects...

I want it so that when I select one option in any of the select tags, it gets removed as an option in all of the others. If I change the selected option, it then becomes available again in all of the others. Does anyone know how I would be able to do this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but my thought was to keep track of which `select` have chosen which option with a object called `chosenObjects` then filtering results based on that information.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function ExampleComponent() {
    const selectNames = ["select1", "select2"];
    const [options] = useState([
        {
            label: 'Option 1',
            value: 'option1'
        },
        {
            label: 'Option 2',
            value: 'option2'
        },
        {
            label: 'Option 3',
            value: 'option3'
        }
    ]);


    const [chosenOptions, setChosenOptions] = useState({});

    const isChosenByOther = (optionValue, selectName) => {
        for (let key in chosenOptions) {
            if (key !== selectName) {
                if (chosenOptions[key] === optionValue) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    const handleChange = (ev) => {
        setChosenOptions({...chosenOptions, [ev.target.name]: ev.target.value});
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {selectNames.map((name, index) => {
                return (
                    <select name={name} key={index} onChange={handleChange} value={chosenOptions[name] || ''}
                            required={index === 0}>
                        <option value=''/>
                        {options.filter(({value}) => !isChosenByOther(value, name))
                            .map(({label, value}, oIndex) =>
                                <option value={value} key={oIndex}>{label}</option>)
                        }
                    </select>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

You can also conditionally disable your empty string valued `option` after something is chosen:

```
<div>
    {selectNames.map((name, index) => {
        return (
            <select name={name} key={index} onChange={handleChange} value={chosenOptions[name] || ''}
                    required={index === 0}>
                <option value='' disabled={chosenOptions[name]}>Choose Option</option>
                {options.filter(({value}) => !isChosenByOther(value, name))
                    .map(({label, value}, oIndex) =>
                        <option value={value} key={oIndex}>{label}</option>)
                }
            </select>
        )
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works. The only thing that I am needing help with is setting the initial option to a blank label as I have in my original question, would you be able to help with that? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, how am I able to make it so that only the first select has the `required` attribute, but none of the subsequent ones? Thanks

Comment: Edited so that first element only is required, and has blank options as in original question.

Comment: Works great! Thank you for the help once again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `state` to manage the value and share it between two `select`s.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function ExampleComponent() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('option0')
    handleChange = (e) => {
      setValue(e.target.value)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="option0"></option>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>

            <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="option0"></option>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use state? You can use same datasource for options and also same event handlers for all selects.

```
export default function ExampleComponent() {
  state = {
    options: [
      {
        name: 'Option 1',
        value: 'option1'
      },
      {
        name: 'Option 2',
        value: 'option2'
      },
      {
        name: 'Option 3',
        value: 'option3'
      }
    ]
  };

  onChangeSelect = event => {
    // do something
    this.setState({
      options: this.state.options.filter(
        option => option.value !== event.target.value
      )
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select required name="select1" onChange={onChangeSelect}>
        <option label=" "></option>
        {this.state.options.map(option => (
          <option value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <select name="select2" onChange={onChangeSelect}>
        <option label=" "></option>
        {this.state.options.map(option => (
          <option value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have it set up using state now but what do I put in `onChangeSelect` in order to remove it from other `<select>`s when selected?

Comment: remove selected from `options` array

Comment: This is a function component not a class component that extends `React.Component`, you don't have access to `this.state` or `this.setState` in this environment.

Comment: I have seen the edit, there are currently two problems in the code. One, when you select an option it does not display, it still shows up as blank in the select field. It does remove the option from the other select, but the second problem is when I change the selected option it does not add it back to the other select, the option is removed permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the state of multiple `Select` elements, and then conditionally render the options for each one.

I'll use some bits from the other answers and show how to make it work. Edited to keep the options in the same order.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
function ExampleComponent() {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState({});
    const options = [
        {
            name: 'Option 1',
            value: 'option1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Option 2',
            value: 'option2'
        },
        {
            name: 'Option 3',
            value: 'option3'
        }
    ]

    // list of select names
    const selectNames = [
        "select1",
        "select2"
    ]

    handleChange = (e) => {
        // update the value for the given select
        myState[e.target.name] = e.target.value
        setMyState(myState)
    }

    const inUseValues = Object.values(myState);

      console.log(inUseValues)

    // get the options for given name
    getOptions = (name) =>
        options.filter(option => !inUseValues.includes(option.value) || myState[name]==option.value)
        .map(option => (
            <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
        ))

    // render all select controls
    const selectRender = selectNames.map(name => (
        <select key={name} required name="{name}" value={myState[name]} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option label=" "></option>
            {getOptions(name)}
        </select>
        ))

    return (
        <div>
            {selectRender}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it does not remove the options from other selects, one does not affect the other still

Comment: this is debugged and working now, but another answer does basically the same thing.